# delphi can't import SAPI 5.1

Tags: delphi, sapi

I'm trying to do some speech recognition with delphi and found this simple project which works great but I can't use it cause I'm not able to import SAPI 5.1.
In the "Import Type Library" Window I can find SAPI 5.4 but sadly I couldn't get it to work with that. Now I'm wondering whether there is a way to import SAPI 5.1 so I can use the example below and extend it for my needs.

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, SpeechLib_TLB, StdCtrls;

const SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE = -1;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    SpSharedRecoContext1: TSpSharedRecoContext;
    MyGrammar : ISpeechRecoGrammar;
    procedure SpSharedRecoContext1Recognition(ASender: TObject;
                                              StreamNumber: Integer;
                                              StreamPosition: OleVariant;
                                              RecognitionType: SpeechRecognitionType;
                                              const Result: ISpeechRecoResult);
    procedure SpSharedRecoContext1Hypothesis(ASender: TObject;
                                             StreamNumber: Integer;
                                             StreamPosition: OleVariant;
                                             const Result: ISpeechRecoResult);
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
 SpSharedRecoContext1.Free;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SpSharedRecoContext1 := TSpSharedRecoContext.Create(self);
  SpSharedRecoContext1.OnRecognition   := SpSharedRecoContext1Recognition;
  SpSharedRecoContext1.OnHypothesis    := SpSharedRecoContext1Hypothesis;
  MyGrammar := SpSharedRecoContext1.CreateGrammar(0);
  MyGrammar.DictationSetState(SGDSActive);
end;

procedure TForm3.SpSharedRecoContext1Recognition(ASender: TObject;
                                                 StreamNumber: Integer;
                                                 StreamPosition: OleVariant;
                                                 RecognitionType: SpeechRecognitionType;
                                                 const Result: ISpeechRecoResult);
begin
 Caption := '';
 Memo1.Lines.Add(Result.PhraseInfo.GetText(SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE,SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE,true));
end;

procedure TForm3.SpSharedRecoContext1Hypothesis(ASender: TObject;
                                                StreamNumber: Integer;
                                                StreamPosition: OleVariant;
                                                const Result: ISpeechRecoResult);
begin
 Caption := 'I am listening...';
end;


end.
```

Any help is appreciated,

thx timo314

Edit:
I got delphi 6 Personal Edition
SAPI 5.1 is not listed in the "import Type Library" Window
When Compiling I get errors at line 46 and 47 saying "Incompatible Types Parameter Lists differ"

I noticed that the SpeechLib_TLB.pas that came with the example differs from the one the import created in my "Import" Directory.
After I change the Parameter lists of SpSharedRecoContext1Recognition and SpSharedRecoContext1Hypothesis the Application runs but the procedures aren't called. As if the Programm doesn't notice that someone is speaking.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What version of Delphi? What does "can't import" mean? Do you mean it's not installed with your Windows version, but you have SAPI 5.4? If so, 5.4 is backwardly compatible with earlier versions; what problems are you having? Do you get error messages? Please edit your question, and remember when doing so that we only have the information you give us to use to try and help you solve your problem. If you don't tell us, we can't know - we can't see your screen or code or read your mind from here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell with what you provided, but for me `RecognitionType` is a `TOleEnum` and I would use
`Memo1.Lines.Add(Result.PhraseInfo.GetText(0,SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE,true));`
instead of
`Memo1.Lines.Add(Result.PhraseInfo.GetText(SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE,SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE,true));`
As the first param specifies the first element to retrieve.

I would also set `SpSharedRecoContext1.EventInterests := SREAllEvents;`

You might find some useful examples and info on [my blog](http://fgaillard.com/tag/speech/)...

PS: I had no problem with SAPI 5.4, but never tried it on D6....

Comment: Thanks for your reply i'll take a look at your site. Regarding to this WepPage [link(]http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2002/Speech/SAPI51/SAPI51.htm#GramNotify) things seem to be a bit different in delphi 6 and earlier. But neither your solution nor a change to Add(Result.PhraseInfo.GetText) regarding the above mentioned site is solving the problem for me.

Comment: Just found this:<br> DELPHI 6 Users IMPORTANT
There is a bug in the type library import in Delphi 6 see article "Delphi 6 - Imported Automation Events Bug". This sample will still work with the unit created by the type libary import in Delphi 6 but only because none of the events for the component are used. If you want to use any of the SPVoice events you will need to read article "Delphi 6 - Imported Automation Events Bug". <br> See [link](http://delphicikk.atw.hu/listaz.php?id=2380&oldal=51) Hope i'll find a solution in there, if so i'll post it here.

Comment: [On this Site](http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=47605) someone showed some hackish solution to this issue, but replacing my SpeechLib_TLB with one that was created through delphi 5 made the sample project from [here](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2002/Speech/SAPI51/SAPI51.htm#DSR) work without any error, so i'll built my app upon that example. Thanks for your time and help, timo314